# Android: How to know the driver loaded for my device

Tags: android, linux, drivers

I am trying to find out what driver has been loaded for the light sensor on my nexus 7 device. I found out that lsmod and modinfo do not work on android. Is there a way I can list all the loaded drivers and descriptions so that I know the exact driver that has been loaded by the linux kernel. 
I tired to find out the light sensor device and then find out the driver. Wasn't helpful.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The /proc/modules interface does seem to have been recently disabled.  But that would only cover drivers built as modules, and a lot of basic functionality tends to be implemented with driver code compiled directly into the kernel.

/proc/config.gz now appears to be missing, too.

Android devices normally run a Linux kernel, the licensing terms of which require that anyone distributing a binary version offer to provide you with full sources for the version distributed, including configuration information.

Thus theoretically the way to determine what is running in kernel context on your device is to make a GPL source request from the vendor.

Pragmatically, it is likely that those in the modding community may already have a fairly good idea, and be able to answer you in more useful detail if you ask a question about a specific device on a modding site.